# How to get last key with values from array of arrays? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

This is what i am currently using

```
<?php $sidebar = $this->data['sidebar']; 
$lastKey = array_pop(array_keys($sidebar));
$sidebar = $this->data['sidebar'][$lastKey]; ?>
<?php foreach($sidebar as $key => $item) { ?>
<li id="<?php echo Sanitizer::escapeId( "pt-$key" ) ?>"<?php
    if ($item['active']) { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['href']) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item['text']) ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

This is what i get (http://pastebin.com/t6Y2ZtMF) when i `print_r($sidebar)`;
I want to get the **last Array** which is *Categories* and turn it into links.

I am new to php, so my method could be wrong even though it works. I is there a right way to pull the *Categories Array* or the above code is good as it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$lastValue = end($array);
$lastKey = key($array); // current key, which is the last since you called end()
```

---

After update:

You don't seem to be needing the key, only the array:

```
<?php $lastSidebarValue = end($this->data['sidebar']); ?>
<?php foreach ($lastSidebarValue as $key => $item) : ?>
    business as usual...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Since you know you want the key `'Categories'` though (not the *last* key), this seems the most logical thing to do:

```
<?php foreach ($this->data['sidebar']['Categories'] as $key => $item) : ?>
    business as usual...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I get only the last key but not the values of the last key

Comment: @user What does your array look like? `print_r($array)`

Comment: @user So the last value is an array itself. What exactly do you expect to get out of this?

Comment: Nothing! since it is array, So how would i go about getting Array->Array->Key-> Values?

Comment: @user You need to clarify what you want. Update your question with the example array and your expected output. Do you want the last value of the innermost array of the last array, or what exactly do you need?

Comment: Honestly i don't even know how to ask this question, but i will try.

Comment: @user Seems you've been overcomplicating things a lot... ;-P

Comment: Ty for your help, the reason i can't use the last code is that the website is multilingual, so Categories will be translated into different language.

Comment: @user That's... weird. Your internal data structures should *not* be subject to translations, only the values the users will see should be.

Comment: Geeeez good point, but there is nothing i can do with my limited php knowledge. FYI the code above is to alter one of the extensions that was written for MediaWiki. Is is a good thing that you brought that up.

Answer (score 2):

I think the end() function would be a great solution: http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php
It basically returns the value of the last element in the array being passed to it.

```
$sidebar = end($sidebar);
```

Comment: from this echo end($sidebar); i get "Array"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you also needed to return the last key along with the last value. You could definitely do what deceze posted for the key.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a key/value pair without popping & pushing the array, set the internal cursor to the end of the array and then use `list` and `each` to get the key & value.

```
// set up your array however you had it
$array = ...;

// move the cursor to the end of the array
end($array);

// use list() and each() to extract your key/value pair    
list($key,$val) = each($array);  

// $key will now have the last key
// $val will have the last value
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps, [end](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'cranberry');
echo end($fruits); // cranberry
```

Comment: i was expecting you to make the obvious changes, i was just quoting from the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `end()` instead of `array_pop()`. But both works for the **last element** of the array. The only difference is `end()` **points out** the **last element** of the array without effecting it and `array_pop()` **pops** the element off the **end** of array.

Please go through the following links for detail information

[end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) | [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: i see, does this look fine $lastKey = end(array_keys($sidebar));